# Should I make a class polymorphic if only one of its methods should behave differently depending on the object's data type?

Tags: c++

I have a class `Group` containing a vector of objects of another class `Entry`. Inside the `Group` I need to frequently access the elements of this vector(either consequently and in random order). The `Entry` class can represent a data of two different types with the same properties(size, content, creation time etc.). So all of the members and methods of the `Entry` class are the same for both data types, except for one method, that should behave differently depending on the type of the data. It looks like this:

```
class Entry
{
    public:
        // ...
        void someMethod();
        // ...
    private:
        TYPE type_;
        // ...
};


class Group
{
    private:
        // ...
        std::vector<Entry> entries_;
        // ...
};

void Entry::someMethod()
{
    if (type_ == certainType)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
    else if (type_ == anotherType)
    {
        // Do some different stuff
    }
}
```

Given the abilities of C++ regarding OOP, this approach seems unnatural to me. I am thinking about creation of two distinct classes inherited from the `Entry` class and overriding only this `someMethod()` in those classes:

```
class Entry
{
    // ...
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
    // ...
};

class EntryType1 : public Entry
{
    // override someMethod() here
};

class EntryType2 : public Entry
{
    // override someMethod() here
};
```

But doing so means reducing the efficiency of cache usage, because now inside the `Group` class I have to replace the vector of `Entry` objects placed in a contiguous memory area with the vector of pointers to `Entry` base class objects scattered all over the memory address space.

The question is - is it worth it to make a class polymorphic just because of one only among many other of its methods is needed to behave differently depending on the data type? Is there any better approach?

Comment: Your class could have a function pointer member variable that is set to the function that has the behavior for that flavor of Entry.

Comment: If there are a finite, small number of entries and you know you'll never add new ones, just use an `enum` or an `std::variant`. If you think the thing needs to be extensible and the method is fundamental to `Entry` behavior, consider subclassing. If the method is only one part of `Entry`'s behavior, consider splitting this part into a separate class (which is polymorphic) or, as Eljay said, use a function pointer member.

Comment: Sometimes it's best to encapsulate this polymorphic functionality into another class. E.g. if you have a `Customer` class that could pay by cash, credit, debit, check, maybe there should be a polymorphic `PaymentMethod` that the non-polymorphic `Customer` should have as a member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it worth it to make a class polymorphic just because of one only among many other of its method is needed to behave differently depending on the data type?

Runtime polymorphism starts to provide undeniable net value when the class hierarchy is deep, or may grow arbitrarily in future.  So, if this code is just used in the private implementation of a small library you're writing, start with what's more efficient if you have real reason to care about efficiency (`type_` and `if`), then it's not much work to change it later anyway.  If lots of client code may start to depend your choices here though, making it difficult to change later, and there's some prospect of further versions of `someMethod()` being needed, it's probably better to start with the virtual dispatch approach.

> Is there any better approach?

Again - what's "better" takes shape at scale and depends on how the code is depended upon, updated etc..  Other possible approaches include using a `std::variant<EntryType1, EntryType2>`, or even a `std::any` object, function pointers....

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely sure that there are only two types of `Entry`, then using an `if` inside the function's implementation is, to me, a perfectly valid approach. <s>In this case, I would advise you to use `if constexpr` to further indicate that this is a compile-time behavioral decision and not a runtime one.</s> (As pointed out by Tony Delroy, `if constexpr` is not viable).

If, however, you are unsure if you are going to need more `Entry` types in the future, the `if` approach would only hurt you in the long run. If you need the scalability, I would advise you to make the `Entry` class hold a `std::function` internally for only *that specific behavior* that needs polymorphism: this way you're only paying for indirection when you actually need the functionality.

You could also make two factory functions `make_Entry1` and `make_Entry2` that construct an `Entry` passing it the specific `std::function` that yields the desired behavior.

Comment: *"use `if constexpr` to further indicate that this is a compile-time behavioral decision"* - but it *is* a runtime one.